# Check password - Where is the error in code?

Tags: javascript

The password authentication code, but does not work.. Where is the error in my code?

**JS:**

```
function checkPass() {
var pass = document.getElementById('pass');
var pass2 = document.getElementById('pass2');

if(pass != pass2) {
document.layers.passResponse.innerHTML = "Passwords did not Match!";
} else {
document.layers.passResponse.innerHTML = "Passwords Match!";
}
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="form-left">Password * </div>
<div class="form-right"><input type="password" id="pass" name="pass" class="form-input" /></div>
<div class="form-left">Confirm Password *</div>
<div class="form-right"><input type="password" id="pass2" name="pass2" class="form-input" /></div>
```

Comment: Among other things, you are comparing **elements**, not their **values**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are compare two html elements, not the values of them.

`if(pass1 != pass2) {`

Should be

```
if(pass1.value != pass2.value) {
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you are trying to compare two input elements, and not their values. You need to access their value properties. You should also use the strict comparison operator where possible.

```
if ( pass1.value !== pass2.value )
```

Second, you are trying to use `document.layers`, which is a proprietary property seen in Netscape 4.

You need a more modern guide, try the W3C's [JavaScript core skils](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Web_Standards_Curriculum#JavaScript_core_skills), the section on Traversing the DOM covers the area you are dealing with (but if you have been working with guides that mention `layers` you are likely to benefit from starting at the beginning).

Answer (score 0):

```
if(pass.value != pass2.value) {
document.layers.passResponse.innerHTML = "Passwords did not Match!";
} else {
document.layers.passResponse.innerHTML = "Passwords Match!";
}
}
```

Use the code above.